# Where do I find a comparison of different STL containers complexity (performance)?

Tags: c++, performance, stl, complexity-theory

I googled quite a while in order to find out a comparison that shows the differences in complexity for all STL-Containers on insert/push erase/pop etc. I did not find any. Also not in all of my STL Books. Any hint?

I know some rules of thumb of course. But where is a definition?

Comment: There is a complexity comparison table here: [http://devmentor.org/references/stl/stl.php](http://devmentor.org/references/stl/stl.php)

Comment: I recommend not deleting this question, as the titles are sufficiently different.

Comment: http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~riesbeck/programming/c++/stl-summary.html

Answer (score 3):

Try with

http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/complexity.html

http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/table_of_contents.html

From complexity.html:

> Fundamentally, it is difficult to
>   define the notion of asymptotic
>   algorithm complexity precisely for
>   real computer hardware instead of an
>   abstract machine model. Thus we settle
>   for the following guidelines:
>
> 1. For an algorithm A to have running time O(f(n)), there must be a
>      corresponding algorithm A' that is
>      correct on machines with arbitrarily
>      long pointer and size_t types, such
>      that A and A' perform essentially the
>      same sequence of operations on the
>      actual hardware. (In simple cases A
>      and A' will be the same. In other
>      cases A may have been simplified with
>      the knowledge that adresses are
>      bounded.) For inputs of sufficiently
>      large size n, A' must take at most
>      time Cf(n), where C is a constant,
>      independent of both n and the address
>      size. (Pointer, size_t, and ptrdiff_t
>      operations are presumed to take
>      constant time independent of their
>      size.)
> 2. All container or iterator complexity specifications refer to
>      amortized complexity. An individual
>      operation may take longer than
>      specified. But any sufficiently long
>      sequence of operations on the same
>      container or iterator will take at
>      most as long as the corresponding sum
>      of the specified operation costs.
> 3. Algorithms specify either worst-case or average case
>      performance, and identify which.
>      Unless otherwise stated, averages
>      assume that container elements are
>      chosen from a finite type with more
>      possible values than the size of the
>      container, and that container elements
>      are independently uniformly
>      distributed.
> 4. A complexity specification for an operation f assumes that operations
>      invoked by f require at most the
>      specified runtime. But algorithms
>      generally remain appropriate if the
>      invoked operations are no more than a
>      logarithmic factor slower than
>      specified in the expected case.
> 5. If operations are more expensive than assumed by a function F in the
>      current STL, then F will slow down at
>      most in proportion to the added cost.
>      Any future operations that fail to
>      satisfy this property will make that
>      explicit.
>
>    To make this precise, assume F is specified to use time f(m) for
>      input of size m. F uses operations Gk,
>      with specified running times gk(n) on
>      input size n. If F is used in a
>      context in which each Gk is slower
>      than expected by at most a factor
>      h(n), then F slows down by at most a
>      factor h(m). This holds because none
>      of the current algorithms ever apply
>      the operations Gk to inputs
>      significantly larger than m.

Answer (score 1):

ISO C++ Standard defines the complexity of algorithms and container access methods, where required. Anywhere else (if not explicitly stated) all bets are off and a library implementor is free to do their own implementation.

For example you can assume that maps and sets are implemented using red-black trees, but there is no requirement to do so. Many algorithms are overloaded or specialized for particular iterator categories (like Random Access Iterator) and sometimes might be even optimized to perform from special hardware (like XMM register and execute some some operations in parallel).

Sometimes you really have to logically assume how much an operation might cost, due to other requirements, like splice in std::list must have O(1) complexity => length has O(n).

I have the book from N. Josuttis
[C++ Standard Library - Tutorial And Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201379260)
and all these aspects are well covered there.

Best Regards,
Ovanes

Comment: According to www.cplusplus.com - "Constant on all cases, except when x is a list object different than *this in the third function version, in which case it is linear in the range between first and last (iterator advance)."

This would seem to imply that length can still be implemented in O(n) time, since in the case that you are splicing a range of values splice can be linear (all other cases are as simple as adding the two sizes together).

Of course it's possible that some implementations still have O(n) size() for list.

Comment: Yes, this was just an example. cplusplus.com is a nice site, but ISO C++ Standard is a definite answer. Information at cplusplus.com is taken from the standard (probably interpreted or adapted), but nothing is as definite as C++ standard. As I already stated above, if standard does not state smth. than it is up to the compiler vendor and cplusplus.com will be of no help either. I think especially in case of C++ it is very important to double check suspicious things there. Finding things in standard will make you find much more related things and greatly grow the skills as C++ developer.

Comment: Actually I double-checked the standard and it clearly states for most algorithms and most container access members or operations their complexity. An example: 
25.3.5.2 set_union [lib.set.union] 
...  
Effects: Constructs a sorted union of the elements from the two ranges; ...  
Requires: The resulting range shall not overlap with either of the original ranges.  
Returns: The end of the constructed range. Complexity: At most 2 * ((last1 - first1) + (last2 - first2)) - 1 comparisons.  
Notes: Stable: if an element is present in both ranges, the one from the first range is copied.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this report on STL, Boost and  array container performance

http://landenlabs.com/code/perf-stl/perf-stl.html